# Scrolled composite content is not shown in multi page wizard

Tags: java, swt, rcp, eclipse-neon, scrolledcomposite

I'm using Eclipse Neon 4.6.  When I open a multi-page wizard, 
and its second page contents is a scrolled composite, the page comes up blank 
no widgets at all.  When I resize or maximize the editor, then the contents are displayed and the development environment I am using is Ubuntu Linux.
Please help to resolve the issue.

Please find the below code snippet

scrollBar = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL
        | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.RESIZE);

```
scrollBar.setLayout(new FillLayout());
scrollBar.setExpandHorizontal(true);

scrollBar.setExpandVertical(true);
scrollBar.setLayoutData(newGrig);

messageGroup = new Composite(scrollBar, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER);
GridLayout moduleLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);

moduleLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
messageGroup.setLayout(moduleLayout);

messageGroup.setBackground(container.getBackground());
messageGroup.setLayoutData(newGrig);

scrollBar.setContent(messageGroup);


/**
 * if size exceeds moduleGrid.size, enable scrollbar
 */
scrollBar.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void controlResized(ControlEvent e)
    {
    scrollBar.setMinSize(messageGroup.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT,
        SWT.DEFAULT));
    }
});
```

Comment: Show us the code...

Comment: I have added the code in the description

Comment: Is there a call `pack()`after the initialization?

Comment: For the scrolled composite you are asking?. No I am not doing that.

Comment: Any other initial layout setting method?

Comment: The parent container is also a Scrolled composite.And we are setting scrollBar.setLayout(new FillLayout()); for the parent container as well.

Comment: When I googled it is observed like know issue with eclipse.Any idea how to resolve it

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487160 Tried with the solutions explained in the above link as well. Still I am facing the same issue.